# serialize() 01 input y 01 select con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialización

Como puedo capturar el valor de un select y un input con Jquery, estoy haciendo esto:

```
$("#gradoNew").change(function(){       
var gradoNew= $("#gradoNew", "#idJefeU").serialize();   
    console.log(gradoNew);      
$.ajax({
    data: gradoNew,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "guardarGrado.php",        
})`
```

y en el html:

```
<select name="gradoNew" id="gradoNew" class="form-control" required>..</select>
<input id="jefeNew" name="jefeNew" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu comentario en la respuesta anterior, lo puedes hacer asi;

```
$("#gradoNew").change(function(){            
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      gradoNew: $("#gradoNew").val(),
      idJefeU: $("#idJefeU").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "guardarGrado.php",        
 })
```

otra opción es con FormData:

```
new form = new FormData()
form.append("value_name", "value");
form.append("value_name2", "value2");

$.ajax({
  ...
  data: form,
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form id="miForm">
    <select name="gradoNew" id="gradoNew" class="form-control" required>..</select>
    <input id="jefeNew" name="jefeNew" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
</form>
```

JS

```
let gradoNew = $('#miForm').serialize();
```

PHP

```
echo $_POST['gradoNew']. " ".$_POST['jefeNew'];
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero SOLO necesito enviar los datos de esos 02 CONTROLES, ya q en mi formulario hay varios controles por lo q no puedo usar $(#miForm).serialize().